# How to set border color only for angles

Tags: react-native

Faced with the further problem: cant set color only for angles and top side [problem angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQUyW.jpg).
There is my code of element:

```
container: {
    backgroundColor: '#0d1117',
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    borderTopWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'white',
}
```

If trying to set left and right width then all side changing color.
Thought about add another element, but looks like bad idea.
Do have somebody any ideas?